# how to install glib2 package in docker

Tags: docker, centos6.5

I use docker to install centos 6.5 and opensource c++ mysql proxy : DBPORXY(https://github.com/Meituan-Dianping/DBProxy.git), when I run into the last command, I failed.From the error info, I think that is glib2 problem,but I have installed glib2! that is my public docker : [
docker pull xujianhai/dbproxy], the method I use to implement glib2 : 
cd  glib-2.42.0

```
./configure
make
make install
vi /etc/ld.so.conf
add a row and exit: /usr/local/lib
ldconfig
```

the detail error message when I run into the last command :

```
bash-4.1# make
make  all-recursive
make[1]: Entering directory `/DBProxy'
Making all in src
make[2]: Entering directory `/DBProxy/src'
make  all-am
make[3]: Entering directory `/DBProxy/src'
/bin/sh ../libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..  -I/usr/include/mysql -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/glib-2.0/include   -pthread -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/glib-2.0/include   -ggdb   -g -O0 -MT libmysql_chassis_glibext_la-glib-ext.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libmysql_chassis_glibext_la-glib-ext.Tpo -c -o libmysql_chassis_glibext_la-glib-ext.lo `test -f 'glib-ext.c' || echo './'`glib-ext.c
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -I/usr/include/mysql -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/glib-2.0/include -pthread -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/glib-2.0/include -ggdb -g -O0 -MT libmysql_chassis_glibext_la-glib-ext.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libmysql_chassis_glibext_la-glib-ext.Tpo -c glib-ext.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/libmysql_chassis_glibext_la-glib-ext.o
glib-ext.c: In function 'g_string_get_time':
glib-ext.c:121: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'm'
glib-ext.c:121: error: 'm' undeclared (first use in this function)
glib-ext.c:121: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
glib-ext.c:121: error: for each function it appears in.)
make[3]: *** [libmysql_chassis_glibext_la-glib-ext.lo] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/DBProxy/src'
make[2]: *** [all] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/DBProxy/src'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/DBProxy'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: A lot of times errors like this are caused by missing header files. Try installing `glib2-devel` before doing this compile.

Comment: What Dan said.  Also it might be useful to post the lines around `glib-ext.c:121`.  With that in hand, it becomes easy to say "clearly <blah> is somehow undefined at that point."